# TFireMonkeyContainer in C++ projects

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I am trying to use FMX in VCL. Looks like there is a container TFireMonkeyContainer for it. I get an error 'Not an allowed type' on the hpp it generates. Here is how the code where it errors looks like

```
__property HWND FireMonkeyFormHandle = {read=GetHostedFMXFormWindowHandle, nodefault};
```

Basically I compiled the 10.1 seattle project from github and used the bpl and hpp it generated.

Has anyone worked with this container in C++?

Thanks.

Comment: `FireMonkeyFormHandle` is declared as `published`. `HWND` is not a valid data type for a published property. And besides, the property is read-only anyway, which is another no-no for published properties. The author has made a coding mistake. Alter `Parnassus.FMXContainer.pas` to make `FireMonkeyFormHandle` be `public` instead of `published` and then recompile.

Comment: That takes care of that error. But now I get fmx and vcl ambiguity error. Using fully scoped type doesn't seem to solve it. The ide prevents saving and the dfm does not come up. Maybe fmx and vcl cannot be mixed in C++ builder. Thanks.

Comment: Delphi-generated HPP files have `using namespace ...` statements at the bottom of them, so it is likely that same-named VCL and FMX symbols are being dumped into the global namespace, thus the ambiguities. Look in the HPP files to see the specific `NO_USING_NAMESPACE_...` conditionals they use, and then define those conditionals in your C++ project options as needed. Or, just define the `DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE` conditional instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks...I defined `NO_USING_NAMESPACE_FMX_FORMS` because both the vcl and fmx forms are included in their hpp. It now compiles and runs. But the fmx form which I want to contain is not visible. I think I have to contact the authors and see if I get a response back. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved in a recent update, and it can now be used in a C++ project fine. You may need to take care when both VCL and FMX headers are included (as in your define `NO_USING_NAMESPACE_FMX_FORMS` comment.)  Please pull [the latest from github](https://github.com/vintagedave/firemonkey-container).